# In general/Generally: 概【がい】して, 一般【いっぱん】に, 全体【ぜんたい】に, 総【そう】じて, なべて, 一体{いったい}に, etc

Tags: synonyms, word-choice

When I look at them in the dictionary, they all mean the same thing. How to know which one to use?

If I want to say: "Generally, I go to school by bus" or "Generally, people grow taller" or even "Generally, I like cats", which one should I use? Or can several of them be used for the same sentence?

Examples would be much appreciated.

**Edit**: Okay, some of the sentences I gave lack context. Here would be the entire sentence:

> "Generally, people grow taller but some suffers from dwarfism"
>
> "Generally, I like cats but this one is horrible"

Comment: Is that really なべて？　Not　すべて？

Comment: Haha, actually I found both in the dictionary ... Seriously, there are too many "general" words ...

Comment: How about `通常`? That seems to fit your sentences.

Comment: If you add なべて, I'd add おしなべて too

Comment: 全般的に would be more common than 一体に, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Ignoring the details or minor exceptions, as a tendency: 概して, 総じて, (おし)なべて

> 概して/総じて/おしなべて、日本人は神経質で、アメリカ人は雑だ。
>   'Generally, Japanese are highly strung and Americans are coarse/sloppy.'

- Generalizing: 一般に

> 4は2+2と表される。一般に、4以上の偶数は、2つの素数の和で表される。
>   '4 is expressed 2+2. In general, an even number that is four or greater can be expressed as the sum of two primes.'

- As a whole, adding up: 全体(的)に

> 個個の四半期で見れば赤字もあったが、この一年では全体的に黒字だ。
>   'There were quarters that we had deficit, but for this year as a whole, we gained profit.'

- The hell, on earth: 一体に

> 君は一体に何が不満だと言うのか。この馬鹿者が。
>   'What in the hell do you have complaints about? You ass hole.'

Comment: This is really helpful ! Thank you :) (Can you add the translation for the sentences please ?)

Answer (score 3):

Aside from `一般{いっぱん}（的{てき}）に` I don't think I've seen any of those used, but I think I've fairly often seen [`普通【ふつう】`](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?p=%E6%99%AE%E9%80%9A&stype=0&dtype=3), [`通常【つうじょう】`](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E9%80%9A%E5%B8%B8&dtype=3&dname=2na&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=02794400) [`大体【だいたい】`](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E5%A4%A7%E4%BD%93%E3%80%81/UTF-8/) and [`大抵【たいてい】`](http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch?enc=UTF-8&p=%E5%A4%A7%E6%8A%B5&dtype=3&dname=2na&stype=0&pagenum=1&index=02534100) used for "generally" (Japanese sentences from Tatoeba):

> 麻雀は普通、四人で遊ぶゲームです。
>   Mahjong is [generally/in general] a game played by 4 people.
>
> 母は大抵大変忙しかった。
>   My mother was in general extremely busy.
>
> 彼は、通常バスで学校へ行きます。
>   He generally goes to school by bus.
>
> ７月の天候はだいたい暑い。
>   The weather is generally hot in July.

<sub>(Disclaimer: I'm not sure how correct/natural these are):</sub>

> 大抵の人は背が伸びるが、小人症という病気にかかる人もいる。
>   Most people grow taller, but there are also some who suffer from dwarfism.
>
> 普通、猫は好きなんだけど、この猫はいやだ！
>   Generally, I like cats but this one is horrible!

Answer (score 0):

1. To understand better what the difference is, you must look at the meaning of the kanjis…
2. For your questions: I'd say

   - 普段は、バスで通学します -> meaning "usually"
   - 一般的に、人が成長します -> meaning "as a law/rule"
   - not meaningful to me, so I can't translate.

Comment: I still don't know what one would mean by the 2nd sentence...